# PHPmailer not sending mail in only Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, phpmailer

I'm having a bit of an issue with my PHPmailer service. I've tested it multiple times in Internet Explorer and Chrome. It works great. It just doesn't send anything when I try Firefox.

My domain shows it has PTR set up as well. I've checked the logs, and I've gotten no problems. Kind of at a loss for what to do.

HTML:

```
<div class = "myBox" ng-show="isSet(3)" ng-controller="ContactController">


<!-- Name, Company, Title, Address, City, State, County, Phone, Email, Type of request(new equipment or other pics), select one(item), comments -->
    <h2 class="topProductTitle"><b>Request a Quote:</b></h2><br>
    <form ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputName.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" maxlength="25" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputCompany.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputCompany" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Company</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputCompany" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCompany" name="inputCompany" placeholder="Company" maxlength="25" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputTitle.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputTitle" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputTitle" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" name="inputTitle" placeholder="Title" maxlength="25" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputAddress.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputAddress" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputAddress" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="inputAddress" placeholder="Address" maxlength="40" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputCity.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputCity" class="col-lg-2 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputCity" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="inputCity" placeholder="City" maxlength="25" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputState.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputState" class="col-lg-2 control-label">State</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputState" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputState" name="inputState" placeholder="State" maxlength="25" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputPhone.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputPhone" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputPhone" type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone" maxlength="15" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" maxlength="25" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" maxlength="25" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputMessage" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">
                    <h4>Send Message</h4>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
app.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the data.
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) 
    {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'contact-form.php',
                data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-success';
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed! Please fill out all the fields.';
            $scope.result='bg-danger';
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->AddAddress('test2@gmail.com'); //recipient 
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nCompany: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputCompany']) ."\r\n\r\nTitle: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputTitle']) . "\r\n\r\nAddress: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputAddress'])
    . "\r\n\r\nCity: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputCity']) . "\r\n\r\nState: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputState']) . "\r\n\r\nPhone: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputPhone']) . "\r\n\r\nEmail: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputEmail'])
    . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "Test@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "123";
    $mail->setFrom('Test@gmail.com', 'Contact Form');

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
        $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
        echo json_encode($data);

} else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: php is browser agnostic. HTML and angular however are not, so that's where the porblem is

Comment: To clarify- PHP never runs in the browser, it's a server-side software. Meaning that if you see one thing in one browser and another in another, it isn't your PHP. PHP is done executing before the browser ever takes over.

Comment: I do understand that it's server side. What I don't understand is I'm not getting any sort of errors on the server logs. Not sure why it's allowing the mail to be sent when in explorer and chrome, but not firefox.

Comment: dont know either, never used angular, all i can say is debug, debug, debug

Comment: I appreciate it. I'm definitely going to keep at it. Just thought maybe someone may have had a similar issue.

Comment: For future reference, I think I've solved it. The problem was with the <form action="">

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same thing. My mailer works with Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox. This cut-down code, called from the address bar, behaves the same:

```
$subject="FIREFOX test";
$scrnmess = "Howdee doodee";
$email="canthaveit.com";    
$recipient="webmaster@waterfowl.org.uk";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $scrnmess, $headers);
```

Comment: you can use `phpmailer` php class for mail @John